# Java applet on website?

Tags: html, applet

I have been assigned the task of creating a MySQL database which I will host on a server and create a website for a product my friend is selling. The database will store site information such as order information. I have little knowledge of HTML so my solution would be to use a website creater (weebly) and design it. There are then two routes I could take for accessing my database. I am limited to what I can do because all I know is java, c#, and c++. I figured I could create a java applet (which I could easily do) and embed the code of the code of the applet in an applet tag in my weeblys site. There is functionality to embed HTML code in the designer. Using the applet, with my java knowledge I figured I could easily access and insert/extract data from my hosted database. I know that java applets require the JRE and Java browser extension to run, this made me a little hesitant about doing this. Would that be a fine way to approach this project? I need my website to access my database, should I do this in java, or in php. What would be the correct thing for me to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing doesn't sound like a good idea.

First of all, Java Applets are an obsolete technology.  The Java plugin isn't nearly as common now as it was in 1998, and security people have been advising that people disable it for years due to a long string of holes in its security model.

Second, it sounds like you're planning on giving the applet direct access to your database.  This would require that you make your database externally accessible, which will make access control and data validation difficult.

The standard way to implement this sort of thing is to write a server-side web application (you can use PHP, any one of various server-side Java systems, ASPX, or one of many other platforms) that interacts with the database and generates web pages on demand.  The database is hidden behind a firewall, the web application code handles access control and data validation, and the client doesn't need to run unsafe code.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me in a direction to a server side java system? And can I create this using the website creator weeblys and add in any code I need for db access?

Comment: I'm not an expert on web development, but you can start by looking up Java servelets and Java Server Pages (JSP).